# SPFX DatePicker - Property 'selected' does not exist

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, error

I have added DatePicker to my SPFX web part.I wanted to get selected date from DatePicker control.
Find the following code to get date:

```
import {DatePicker} from 'office-ui-fabric-react';

<DatePicker  className="form-control" id="duedate" value={this.state.DueDate} onChange={(event) => this.handleDateChange(event)} selected={this.state.DueDate}/>
```

I get following error because **selected** property does not exist.

> Type '{ className: string; id: string; placeholder: string; value:
> Date; onChange: (event: FormEvent) => void; selected:
> Date; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> IDatePickerProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.   Property 'selected'
> does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IDatePickerProps & {
> children?: ReactNode; }'.

Appreciate your thoughts on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because `selected` property does not exist on DatePicker control.

To check the available properties, refer to [this URL](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/datepicker).

If you are adding this control on a Editform and need to have a date prepopulated , you can add your logic in `value` property as below :

```
<DatePicker  className="form-control" id="duedate" value={this.state.DueDate !== null && this.state.DueDate} onChange={(event) => this.handleDateChange(event)}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use onSelectDate property:
My test code:

```
<DatePicker
              className={controlClass.control}
              label="Start date"
              isRequired={false}
              allowTextInput={true}
              ariaLabel={desc}
              firstDayOfWeek={firstDayOfWeek}
              strings={DayPickerStrings}
    
              onSelectDate={onSelectDate}
            />
const onSelectDate = (date: Date | null | undefined): void => {
      console.log(date)      
    };
```

Test result:
[image]

You could get all properties which we could use here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/datepicker